# HC-05 Bluetooth with Raspberry Pi

Tags: bluetooth, serial-console

I am currently trying to make my HC-05 Bluetooth Adapter (CZ-HC-05 gomcu) work with my Raspberry Pi (B+ V2, lates Raspbian freshly installed).

I used this Tutorial: [A cheap Bluetooth serial port for your Raspberry Pi](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/a-cheap-bluetooth-serial-port-for-your-raspberry-pi)

But I get stuck. My smartphone seems to connect with the RasPi, but I cannot see anything on my Smartphone using Blueterm while the RasPi is starting.

I copied the content from /boot/cmdline.txt and /etc/inittab directly from the tutorial. The previous content looked like this:

/boot/cmdline.txt:

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 console=serial0,115200 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait
```

/etc/inittab: empty

Serial is enabled in raspi-config

What do I do wrong? Since my smartphone is connected I do not think I made an failure while wireing the HC-05.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! The probplem was with my adapter (T-Cobbler GPIO->Breadboard): The labels of RX and TX were switched.